# How to create a spark sql schema for the given JSON String?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema

I am trying to create a schema for this JSON. I tried using *schema_for_json()* and then modifying the column using *from_json()* and the schema received after using the *schema_for_json()* function, but it did not work. If I try writing StructType...I am getting confused...so much nesting. if you try to paste it in a JSON formatter it will be readable.

`{"v":[{"v":{"f":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"19"},{"v":"13"},{"v":null},{"v":"false"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com"},{"v":"Ahuja"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"/Reservations/"},{"v":"/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"/"},{"v":""}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Orders/OrderDetail.aspx?id=c9b8b21c-fada-4f09-8e3e-74fa517d4b76"},{"v":"0"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"undefined"},{"v":"undefined"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":[]},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"0"},{"v":"1"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":[]},{"v":[{"v":{"f":[{"v":"7"},{"v":"1215153891.1572139786"}]}}]},{"v":[]},{"v":"EVENT"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":"No"},{"v":" : "}]}},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":"web"},{"v":[]}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"2"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"19"},{"v":"13"},{"v":null},{"v":"true"},{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com"},{"v":"Ahuja"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"/Reservations/"},{"v":"/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"/"},{"v":""}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Orders/OrderDetail.aspx?id=c9b8b21c-fada-4f09-8e3e-74fa517d4b76"},{"v":"0"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":null},{"v":[]},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"0"},{"v":"1"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":[]},{"v":[{"v":{"f":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"41849:1313880,41853:1313893,46683:1572009,46744:1575763,48144:1639246"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"4"},{"v":"1572922686310.mste1c37"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"5"},{"v":"2019-11-04T21:13:45.537-05:00"}]}}]},{"v":[]},{"v":"PAGE"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":"No"},{"v":" : "}]}},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":"web"},{"v":[]}]}}]}`

**Below is the understandable format of above JSON with line breaks.**

```
{"v":[
{"v":{"f":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"19"},{"v":"13"},{"v":null},{"v":"false"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com"},{"v":"Ahuja"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"/Reservations/"},{"v":"/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"/"},{"v":""}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Orders/OrderDetail.aspx?id=c9b8b21c-fada-4f09-8e3e-74fa517d4b76"},{"v":"0"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"undefined"},{"v":"undefined"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":[]},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"0"},{"v":"1"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":[]},{"v":[{"v":{"f":[{"v":"7"},{"v":"1215153891.1572139786"}]}}]},{"v":[]},{"v":"EVENT"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":"No"},{"v":" : "}]}},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":"(entrance)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":"web"},{"v":[]}]}},

{"v":{"f":[{"v":"2"},{"v":"0"},{"v":"19"},{"v":"13"},{"v":null},{"v":"true"},{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com"},{"v":"Ahuja"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"/Reservations/"},{"v":"/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"/"},{"v":""}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Reservations/SessionTimeout/"},{"v":"www.ahuja.com/Orders/OrderDetail.aspx?id=c9b8b21c-fada-4f09-8e3e-74fa517d4b76"},{"v":"0"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":null},{"v":[]},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"0"},{"v":"1"},{"v":null}]}},{"v":[]},{"v":null},{"v":[]},{"v":[{"v":{"f":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"41849:1313880,41853:1313893,46683:1572009,46744:1575763,48144:1639246"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"4"},{"v":"1572922686310.mste1c37"}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"5"},{"v":"2019-11-04T21:13:45.537-05:00"}]}}]},{"v":[]},{"v":"PAGE"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":"No"},{"v":" : "}]}},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":"(not set)"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}},{"v":"web"},{"v":[]}]}}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reading the JSON using `spark.read.json` will derive schema for you.
I saved the JSON in a file and read it as follows -

```
    val df = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/test.json")
    df.printSchema()
```

This derives schema automatically. I got the following schema,

```
root
 |-- v: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- v: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- f: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
```